# Ionic 4 : Keeping app alive in background

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, background-process

I'm working on an Ionic 4 app working with Angular, and I am trying to keep the app alive in background to send some location data.

So I tried the implementations of cordova's plugins :

- https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
- https://github.com/DavidBriglio/cordova-plugin-foreground-service
- https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

to call this code :

`interval(5000).subscribe(() => console.log("doing things"));`

and add the following permissions in my app config.xml :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

When my app is deployed, I have the same results with all plugins : my treatment is executed only for 5 minutes in background, then it goes to sleep and work again when I open my app.

I suspect the OS make my app sleeping to save the battery but I don't know what to do to avoid this behavior. Any ideas?

At last, the app must be publish on the play store, so I'm worried about the permissions..

Comment: I'm having the same problem Huawei Mate20Pro.  I've even turned off all the battery saving features on the phone. It does however keep on recording the locations to an array, but just not POSTing to my server. When it wakes up, it then does the POST. It's rather weird. I haven't tried the "startOnBoot" feature yet though either.

Comment: Have you tried backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations() and backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations() ?